# How to draw chamfer on PCB for PCIe finger in Eagle

Tags: connector, eaglecad, pcie

I am drawing a pcb with PCIe golden finger. Based on the datasheet shown below, it requires chamfer at the edge of the finger. I am new to PCIe golden finger, was wondering how I can achieve this part.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually for card edge fingers like this, I make a request when sending my gerber/artwork files to the pcb manufacturer. I put the request for chamfer along with a drawing in the same document where I list my stack up (layer order) information.